# Scripting on Mac to automate creation of project folder structure and Mercurial repository/subrepository cloning

Tags: python, macos, bash, mercurial, automator

I frequently (more than once a week) create new 'projects' on my development machine (Mac).  I'm trying to streamline the workflow and automate what I do manually now:

1. Create a project folder structure (I have a template directory structure which I copy)
2. Clone (Mercurial) a boilerplate source code baseline into the newly created folder structure
3. Clone another (Mercurial) repository as a sub-repository of the above baseline repository
4. Modify .hgsub config file (Mercurial) to set up sub-repository
5. Modify hgrc config file (Mercurial) to set up default push folder
6. Do an initial commit (Mercurial)
7. Create a series of aliases in my bash_profile

What's the best (or easiest) way to script the above workflow?  I'd like to pass a couple of parameters such as project name, and sub-repository name, etc.

Is this something that I can easily to in a shell script?  Automator?  Python script?

Thanks.

Prembo.

Comment: Id use a shell script in whatever lang you want bash, python, ruby, whatever. I have something similar i wrote in php.

Comment: The steps in your manual workflow can become the steps in a shell script quite literally. One difference is that you might use `sed` to modify files rather than open them in an editor. You'd use positional parameters or `getopts` to pass in your parameters. See `man bash` for information on those. Then come back and ask specific focused questions.

Comment: C'mon @prodigitalson and Dennis Williamson.  Those are both fine answers so give them as answers.  I'll never understand the wall-flower shy behavior of giving answers as comments, which I'm seeing more and more often.

Comment: Just what I was thinking @Ry4an!

Comment: @Ry4an It's a common thing on SO to not provide something as an answer that does not include code.

Comment: @jordanm I've been around here a long while.  Most of my 789 answers don't have code and a few have been selected.  Comments are great for asking for additional details about their question, but if you think what you're typing might lead them to an answer it's more appropriately made an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The steps in your manual workflow can become the steps in a shell
>   script quite literally. One difference is that you might use sed to
>   modify files rather than open them in an editor. You'd use positional
>   parameters or getopts to pass in your parameters. See man bash for
>   information on those. Then come back and ask specific focused
>   questions.
>
> -- Dennis Williamson